# npm install serialport not working

Tags: node.js, serial-port, npm

When I try installing `serialport` it gives the following warnings:

`sudo npm install serialport --save`

```
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON arduino@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON arduino@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-61-generic
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "serialport" "--save"
npm ERR! node v0.12.4
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.8
npm ERR! path /home/ayushgp/learning/arduino/node_modules/serialport/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/node_modules/request/node_modules/har-validator/bin/har-validator
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT, chmod '/home/ayushgp/learning/arduino/node_modules/serialport/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/node_modules/request/node_modules/har-validator/bin/har-validator'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/ayushgp/learning/arduino/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Which version of node.js you are using?

Comment: I was also facing issues while installing serialport, and tried on different versions of node.js. It worked on 0.12.6

Comment: Were they same issues as mine? @augborn

Comment: not exactly but did you give a try with 0.12.6?

Comment: same issue on node 4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look to this workaround (node version v4.2.4):

```
npm install serialport --build-from-source
```

As I have read in many forums, it is not a good practice to use `sudo` with `npm`.